# volatile keyword in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, volatile

```
class VolatileClass{
volatile bool _loop = true;
    static void Main()
    {
        VolatileClass vObj = new VolatileClass();
        Thread tObj = new Thread(SomeThread);
        tObj.Start(vObj);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        vObj._loop = false;
        Console.WriteLine("_loop value set to false");
    }

    static void SomeThread(object o)
    {
        VolatileClass vObj = (VolatileClass)o;
        Console.WriteLine("Loop started....");
        while (vObj._loop)
        {

        }
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"MyPath\Thread.txt", vObj._loop.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Loop end....");
    }}
```

output:

1. With volatile keyword : Text file created and exe execution ends.
2. Without Volatile keyword: Text file not created and exe does not ends.

After compiling in release mode the volatile keyword makes sure the c# compiler will not optimize or re-arrange the code during compilation. So, after executing the exe there will be no infinite loop and text file was created. If I remove the volatile keyword, then the infinite loop occurs and the text file was not created. The above code was done in console application.

But if I do the same in Web API and build the code in release mode and run the application with debug="false". After running the action method the text file was created with or without volatile keyword. So my question is does the volatile keyword works in Web Application?? or Is there something I am missing??

Below is my Web API code

```
public class NotificationController{

    public void VolatileTest()
    {
        VolatileClass vObj = new VolatileClass();
        Thread tObj = new Thread(VolatileClass.SomeThread);
        tObj.Start(vObj);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        vObj._loop = false;
    }}
public class VolatileClass{
   public bool _loop = true;

    public static void SomeThread(object o)
    {
        VolatileClass vObj = (VolatileClass)o;
        while (vObj._loop)
        {

        }
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"MyPath\Thread.txt", ((VolatileClass)o)._loop.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide Web API example? Without volatile it can work only by chance. So if it's 100% reproducible, probably there is something in your code or machine that makes it work (e.g. variable is already changed when loop starts)

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I have update my code with Web API. If you can   trace out the issue it will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Your examples are not the same. try creating a `new VolatileObj()` inside webapi.

Comment: I have modified Web API code like you suggested, but I see no variation in result. I can see the text file got created in Web API run release mode. Please bare me if I have done anything wrong or I am not understanding what you suggested.

Comment: Can you create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? I don't see any suspicious code that can lead to such behavior.